# GPS route simulator on iOS

Tags: ios, gps, simulator

I'm testing a navigator working on both Android and iOS, on Android I have a lot of fake GPS route simulators. On iOS I tried the xcode embedded location simulator also with gpx track, but every time I need a new track I need to reload application on device, and in any case it is not so efficient, the app+location simulator crashes etc. I'm looking for an app that simulate gps routes, something like Android GPS simulator.
Thanks